# Rekognition: Empty Result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

**Hey Stackers.**

I'm trying to use Rekognition via the AWS PHP SDK. I do, however have a problem with it. After a long time trying to figure out what's wrong and I still haven't figured it out.  I'm making a request as follows;

```
    $returnData = new \stdClass();

    $this->rekognition = new RekognitionClient([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => 'eu-west-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => 'XXXX',
            'secret' => 'XXXX'
        ]
    ]);

    try {
        $this->basePrint = $basePrint;
        $this->newPrint = $newPrint;

        $faceAnalysis = $this->rekognition->compareFaces([
            'SourceImage' => [
                'Bytes' => base64_decode($this->basePrint),
            ],
            'TargetImage' => [
                'Bytes' => base64_decode($this->newPrint),
            ],
            'Attributes' => ['all']
        ]);

        $returnData->state = "success";
        $returnData->matchResult = $faceAnalysis;


    } catch (RekognitionException $e){

        $returnData->state = "error";
        $returnData->AwsErrorCode = $e->getAwsErrorCode();
        $returnData->AwsErrorMessage = $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
        $returnData->OriginalPrint = $this->basePrint;
        $returnData->NewPrint = $this->newPrint;


    }

return $returnData;
```

That's all fine. No excepton is thrown. However, the result of `$faceAnalysis` is empty. It is null. Without any error thrown. I looked it up in the documentation, and I can't find anything that would result is this behaviour.

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: You pass the input and target images as base64-encoded image bytes (or as references to images in an Amazon S3 bucket).

Comment: @jarmod That's how I had it at first. However, since my variables `$this->basePrint` and `$this->newPrint`come from a Data URL I need to decode them first. AWS will encode them. Otherwise it will return a InvalidImageFormatException.

Comment: I'd be tempted to perform the same test with these two images using the awscli. What does it report?